# Imagick's resize() overlays a black grid on the result image

Tags: php, image, image-processing, imagemagick, imagick

When using ImageMagick to resize (downsize in this case) an image, I get a black grid overlay on the image. The minimum reproducible code is:

```
$modifiedImage = new Imagick("an_image.png");
$modifiedImage->resizeImage(176,256,imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,0,true);
```

When resizing this:

[image: Original image]

I get the following result:

[image: Resized image, showing corruption]

Any ideas as to what is going wrong here?

Comment: Works fine for me with Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-8 Q16 x86_64 2014-12-04

Comment: In my case, ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2014-03-06 Q16. Maybe it was fixed after this version? Thank you for your input :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark Setchell points out, it works in at least a following version of ImageMagick, released after the one I'm using (*6.7.7-10 2014-03-06 Q16*).

I've found a temporary solution, without updating the package, by changing the filter to FILTER_BOX, instead of FILTER_LANCZOS.

```
$modifiedImage->resizeImage($width,$height,imagick::FILTER_BOX,0,true);
```

This correctly generates a downsized image, although the quality is lower (with higher performance/less time in the conversion, however).